# How to integrate Squid authentication with Siteminder SSO on Redhat

Tags: authentication, redhat, squid

Looking for how to implement SSO based authentication on Redhat server for Squid. I am using NTLM authentication from last few years and its working fine and now required to move authentication on Siteminder SSO. I have no clue how to implement.

Please share your thoughts on this.

Regards
Sujit Singh

Answer (score 0):

You should post something on ssohelp.com - great community of IAM professionals....lots of SiteMinder experience there...